# How to Make a Required attribute work on an Input on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation, google-apps-script, web-applications

As mentioned, I am working on information entry page that requires user to enter certain information, and the entry cannot be blank. I looked up the Web and I find the REQUIRED ATTRIBUTE. However, it does not seem to work. What can I do to fix it? the following is what I currently have.

I have been pondering what could possibly be wrong, and here is some of my speculation. it may have got something to do with   part as I failed to make it match to one another properly

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>上傳</title>
    <style type="text/css">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: "微軟正黑體", "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background: #3F51B5;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact input[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "微軟正黑體", "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #FFC107;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #3F51B5;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact input[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="myForm">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3><?=Title?> 上傳系統</h3>
    <h4>會員上傳</h4>
    <div class="form-item">
         <label>Gmail帳號:</label>
         <input type="text" value="<?=useremail?>" name="myEmail" readonly>
         </div>
    <div class="form-item">
         <label>區分:</label>         
         <input type="text" value="<?=params?>" name="params" readonly>
         <input type="hidden" value="<?=sys_id?>" name="sys_id" readonly>
         <input type="hidden" value="<?=Title?>" name="sys_name" readonly>
         </div>
    <div class="form-item">
         <a href="<?=hyper_link?>" target="_blank" >我的</a>
         </div>         
    <? if (setfile =="可傳檔"){ ?>
          <select name="compositions" required>
             <option value="">請選擇</option>
             <option value="general"></option>
             <option value="Five">(五)</option>
             <option value="Ten">(十)</option>
         </select>    
         <input type="file"  name="userFile" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" onchange="checkfile(this);"  > 
         <input type="submit" value="限影像檔(不可使用PDF)" 
           onclick="submitValues(this); return false;">                  
    <? } else  { ?> <div><?=setfile?></div> <br><input type='submit' value='關閉視窗' onclick='window.close();'> <? } ?>   
 

            
  </form>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
<script>
function submitValues(e) {
  e.value = 'Uploading...';
  e.disabled = true;
  const files = [e.parentNode.userFile.files[0]];
  const object = [...e.parentNode].reduce((o, obj) => Object.assign(o, {[obj.name]: obj.value}), {});
  if (files.some(f => f)) 
  {
    Promise.all(
      files.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (file) {
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = f => resolve({filename: file.name, mimeType: file.type, bytes: [...new Int8Array(f.target.result)]});
          fr.onerror = err => reject(err);
          fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        } else {
          //e.disabled = false;
          resolve({});
        }
      }))
    ).then(ar => {
      [object.userFile] = ar;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(object);
    });
    
  }
}
function checkfile(sender) {

  // 可接受的附檔名
  var validExts = new Array(".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg");

  var fileExt = sender.value;
  fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
  fileExt = fileExt.toLowerCase();
  if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
    alert("檔案類型錯誤，可接受的副檔名有：" + validExts.toString());
    sender.value = null;
    return false;
  }
  else return true;
}


    function fileUploaded(status)
    {
        //e.disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>
<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

in basic mode, you can set [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute. but if you want complex validation you should use javascript. for example, you have a form with just name input and it will be required. on submit form handler you should check that input has value or not. for more complex validation you can use yup or joi libraries.

Comment: Thx, the required attribute has already meet my need, but it does not stop user from clicking button if they enter nothing in the script, then the whole program would crash. Therefore, I am wondering if I am not using this properly.

Comment: as I said required attr is just basic. you can't stop the user from clicking the button. for this purpose, you should use pure js or js validation library